# Resharper not happy about XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, resharper

This piece of XAML (in the definition of a `ListView`)

```
    <ListView 
        x:Name="ListViewEpisodes" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Episodes}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Episode Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}"  />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <MenuItem 
                    Header="Delete episode" 
                    Command="w:MainWindow.DeleteEpisode"

                    <!--  PlacementTarget.SelectedItem not OK according to Resharper -->

                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
    </ListView>
```

Resharper warning:

```
Can not resolve property 'SelectedItem' in data context of type 'System.Windows.UIElement'
```

Now, the XAML does work, when I right click an item, and execute the `ContextMenuItem` it does fill the parameter with the content of the `Episode`.

Why is Resharper not happy about this?

Comment: Glad we got that out of the way.

Comment: @McGarnagle That's twice I have seen this comment today. What's the bad taste with ReSharper? I have been using it since 2.0 and love it.

Comment: @TyCobb fair enough.  I've never used it myself.  Some people love it, other people think it's annoying.  Its diagnosis seems to be wrong in this case, anyway.

Comment: @McGarnagle: there's one bug and the whole thing is crap? That's not a valid way to form an opinion, much less a valid criticism. In any case, the latest version of ReSharper has supposedly vastly improved XAML support. Not knowing which version the OP is using, we have no way of knowing if the issue has been resolved already.

Comment: @siride honestly, I wasn't trying to say it's crap, just trying to answer the literal question "what am I doing wrong".  Although actually, VladimirAlmaev makes a good point that i didn't think of.

Comment: @McGarnagle: I don't think you can argue that your comment was anything other than snark (not that I'm not also guilty of that myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty easy to explain. `PlacementTarget` is of type [`UIElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that doesn't have `Tag` member. ReSharper tries to find member with Tag name but it fails.

At compile time ReSharper is right. ReSharper doesn't know what exactly type would be in run time.

Maybe you need to rewrite your binding expression to:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

It's difficult to say precisely, because it isn't obvious what are you trying to achieve with this binding expression.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. I gave it a try, but then found that the problem I had was a bit funkier. I updated the question to reflect the issue better. Sorry for the inconvenience, but could you please have another look and help me out here? +1 for the effort so far!

Comment: As before R# is right at compile time. UIElement really doesn't have the SelectedItem property. R# is a static analysis tool, but binding is a runtime process. You can solve some of R# warnings by defining data types in templates, filling d:DataContext or using notion of attached property. Last versions (8.0 and 8.1) of R# have much improvements for XAML.

Comment: Ah, that's quite the answer. Thanks a lot! I was just not complete sure if I could safely ignore the warning. Thx

Comment: Any time :) If you have worked with Java generics, then you would be easier to treat warnings :)